# Cannot access MySQL on Ubuntu remotely

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

I installed MySQL on DigitalOcean Droplet Ubuntu.

Here is the solution I tried but not working

- Changed the `bind-address` to `0.0.0.0` in `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d` file
- Created an user whose host value is `%`, and give him all access
- Updated the firewall with `sudo ufw allow 3306` (Actually the firewall was inactived by checking with the command `ufw status`)

I also do some check and everything seems fine:

- I used `sudo service mysql status` checked the mysql status is running, here is the result:

```
● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Sat 2023-09-09 03:50:57 UTC; 2h 7min ago
    Process: 172529 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 172537 (mysqld)
     Status: "Server is operational"
      Tasks: 38 (limit: 512)
     Memory: 175.4M
        CPU: 1min 3.671s
     CGroup: /system.slice/mysql.service
             └─172537 /usr/sbin/mysqld
```

- The port 3306 is running by checking with the command `ss -ltn`

```
State        Recv-Q       Send-Q             Local Address:Port              Peer Address:Port      Process      
LISTEN       0            151                      0.0.0.0:3306                   0.0.0.0:*                      
LISTEN       0            4096               127.0.0.53%lo:53                     0.0.0.0:*                      
LISTEN       0            128                      0.0.0.0:22                     0.0.0.0:*                      
LISTEN       0            128                         [::]:22                        [::]:*                      
LISTEN       0            511                            *:443                          *:*                      
LISTEN       0            70                             *:33060                        *:*
```

And the Droplet firewall is alright, basiclly I allow everything go inide and outside:

[image]

I setup a simple http server with 8080 port enabled and I can access it remotely. I don't know what else I can do now. Is there something I missing?

Comment: @Barmar The error code HeidiSQL told me is 10060

Comment: @Barmar the message detail is "Can't connect to server on 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx' (10060)"

Answer (score 0):

After I connect the MySQL successfully on Github Action and another Droplet machine, I believe it was blocked by GFW consider I'm living in China